Android App using C++ for serial USB access
I'm developing an Android application that needs to access a third-party library written in C that accesses the serial port through the command (*pSerialHandle) = open(deviceName, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY); I make the connection through JNI.
I grant the appropriate permissions from the Android application, and everything seems to be correct until the moment I try to open the connection, which gives me the following pernmissions error:
avc: denied { search } for name="usb" dev="tmpfs" ino=18382 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_30:s0:c173,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:usb_device:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 
Device API level: 13
Is it necessary to have the device "rooted" in order to establish the connection through the serial port? Any idea about the solution?

Can you modify the C library?   I assume you are trying to talk to a USB connection.

untrusted_app_30.te is  a SE Linux policy module specific to API level 30 = Android 13 While it's entirely unclear, if you have asked the user for permission on the Java side. Haven't tried with API level 30 yet (no such test-device), but Epson epos.so does just that.

Yes, I can modify the library. I did'n explained  but i'm trying to perform a serial over USB connection.

This won't work out, because android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS (for tmpfs) reads:

Not for use by third-party applications.

Rooting won't make any difference, unless adding the relevant SE Linux policy module while rooted, then one can unroot again. It's about the policy module, which forbids the mounting.

I can't root the device, even if I unroot it afterward. That option is not valid because the application will be massively distributed to be installed on specific devices.
